# Calculate angles from extracted leaf veins

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to calculate the angles that exist between leaf veins in matlab. What I've thought is to detect the lines (veins) using Hough and then calculate the angles. But the result I get when I try to detect the lines is a little strange.

Here is the code:

```
[H,theta,rho] = hough(vein);
P = houghpeaks(H,4);
x = theta(P(:,2));
y = rho(P(:,1));
%lines = houghlines(BW,theta,rho,P,'FillGap',2,'MinLength',4);
lines = houghlines(BW,theta,rho,P);


figure, imshow(vein), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
      xy_long = xy;
   end
end
% highlight the longest line segment
plot(xy_long(:,1),xy_long(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is "strange" ?

Comment: The Hough transform is not useful for curved lines.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you just mixed the names of the matrices.

In your code, there is `vein` matrix and `BW` matrix.
You are using:

- **vein** here: `[H,theta,rho] = hough(vein);`
- **BW** here: `lines = houghlines(BW,theta,rho,P);`

I added the line `BW = vein;`, and the result is much less **strange**:

```
vein = imbinarize(rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuwb0.jpg'))); %Read image, and convert to binary
BW = vein; %Copy vein to BW

[H,theta,rho] = hough(vein);
P = houghpeaks(H,4);
x = theta(P(:,2));
y = rho(P(:,1));
%lines = houghlines(BW,theta,rho,P,'FillGap',2,'MinLength',4);
lines = houghlines(BW,theta,rho,P);


figure, imshow(vein), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
      xy_long = xy;
   end
end
% highlight the longest line segment
plot(xy_long(:,1),xy_long(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
```

Result:

[image]